# How to find out why openssl doesn't work, but netcat works?

Tags: ssl, curl, networking, amazon-ec2, netcat

I have an AWS EC2 Instance running Ubuntu 18.04.

I'd like to curl e.g. `microsoft.com`, but getting this error

```
$ curl https://microsoft.com
curl: (35) OpenSSL SSL_connect: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL in connection to microsoft.com:443
```

going deeper and debugging `openssl`, like this

```
$ openssl s_client -connect microsoft.com:443 -servername microsoft.com
CONNECTED(00000005)
write:errno=104
---
no peer certificate available
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 0 bytes and written 315 bytes
Verification: OK
---
New, (NONE), Cipher is (NONE)
Secure Renegotiation IS NOT supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
No ALPN negotiated
Early data was not sent
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
---
```

I found out, that's probably a firewall issue (https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/158104/testing-tls-with-openssl/158107#158107)

However, netcat works when i'm running

```
$ nc -vz microsoft.com 443
Connection to microsoft.com 443 port [tcp/https] succeeded!
```

How to deal with it?

Comment: did you ever solve this problem? I'm experiencing something similar. Thanks!

Comment: It's company's firewall in my case and it got fixed by the networking team.